# Python: list comprehension with boolean as return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

`B` is a quadratic matrix of size `k`.

I tried the following code

`if [x for x in range(k) if B[x,1] == 1]:`

to get:

For the first `x` in `range(k-1)`, for which `B[x,1] == 1`, stop the for-loop and return `true`, such that the if-statement can be executed. If there is no such `x`, then return `false` and go on in the following code.

Comment: What's a `quadratic matrix of size k`? Can you provide a **[mcve]**?

Comment: Use list comprehension only if you're interested in creating a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(B[x,1] == 1 for x in range(k)):
```

Comment: Does the for-loop stop as soon as the condition is fulfilled for the first x?

Comment: @user4309 Yes `any()` will do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

[arshajii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53266061) is probably right, but if you also want to have the value of the first `x` fulfilling your condition you could do:

```
try:
    x = next(x for x in range(k) if B[x, 1] == 1)
    # Do something with x
except StopIteration:
    # Do something else
```

---

EDIT: Better yet, thanks @arshajii:

```
x = next(x for x in range(k) if B[x, 1] == 1, None)
if x is not None:
    # Do something with x
else:
    # Do something else
```

Comment: You can also use `x = next((x for x in range(k) if B[x, 1] == 1), None)` then check if  `x` is `None` instead of catching an exception.

Comment: @arshajii I always forget about that one and it's so much better, thanks!